# Blazor scrolling to new section

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a list component in blazor which has a collapsable create section, I want when you click to show the create section that it will display and scroll to the create section.
My issue is that StateHasChanged() doesn't update the UI in time, so the element we're trying to scroll to doesn't exist yet when the javascript fires.

Obviously I can get around this with a timeout, but what is a cleaner way to do this in Blazor? Is there a way to say something like `await StateUpdated()`....

My code looks something like this:

```
@page "/createlist"

<div>
    <h3>My List</h3>
    <a @onclick="ToggleAdding">
       Create New
    </a>
</div>

<ul>
    @* list existing items... *@
</ul>

@if (IsAdding)
{
    <div id="some-create-id">
        <h3>Add Section</h3>
        @* create controls here *@
    </div>
}

@code {

    public void ToggleAdding()
    {
        IsAdding = !IsAdding;

        // Need something similar to StateHasChanged(), that is awaitable.

        JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("ScrollIn", new object[] { CreateElementId });
    }
}
```

And the js is simply:

```
ScrollIn = id => {
    let element = document.getElementById(id);
    console.log(!!element ? "SCROLLIN" : "NO FOUND ELE", id);
    if (!!element) { element.scrollIntoView(); }
}
```

Comment: I have the exact same experience with UL/LI using scrollIntoView only difference is that I am calling a webservice to get the items to display. This seems like a bug in the framework to me because I even tried to chain the async task like this: 
await Task.Run(UpdateMessages).ContinueWith(antecedent => ScrollIntoView()); 
Only way to get it to scroll is to add Task.Delay(500) to the ScrollIntoView method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to do the JavaScript call from `OnAfterRender(Async)`. See [ASP.NET Core Razor component lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-6.0) for all the details.

I would actually simplify the JavaScript to be just:

```
ScrollElementIntoView = element => element.scrollIntoView();
```

And then the C# code would be something like this, without using any hardcoded ids:

```
@page "/scroll-test"
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime

<div>
    <h3>My List</h3>
    <a @onclick="ToggleAdding">
        Create New
    </a>
</div>

<ul>
    @foreach (var x in Enumerable.Range(0, 100)) {
        <li>@x</li>
    }
</ul>

@if (IsAdding)
{
    <div @ref="AddSectionRef">
        <h3>Add Section</h3>
    </div>
}

@code {
    bool IsAdding { get; set; }
    ElementReference AddSectionRef { get; set; }
    List<Func<Task>> AfterRenderAsyncJobs = new();

    private void ToggleAdding() {
        IsAdding = !IsAdding;
        AfterRenderAsyncJobs.Add(ScrollToAddSection);
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    private async Task ScrollToAddSection() {
        await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("ScrollElementIntoView", AddSectionRef);
    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender) {
        while (AfterRenderAsyncJobs.Any()) {
            var job = AfterRenderAsyncJobs.First();
            AfterRenderAsyncJobs.Remove(job);
            await job.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have easy access to test this at present but it sounds like it would work so I will accept it as the answer. Thanks!